# How to get transient value in java serialization

Tags: java, serialization

I have a problem that i can't get value of transient object variable's value that variable contains another object reference in itself. Serializable Dog class have a transient value named Not serializable Collar. Collar have non serializable object reference itself. How could i get Collar value in serialization and deserialization. Please solve this.

### **Dog.java**

```
package main;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Dog implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name;
    private transient Collar collar;

    public Dog(String name, Collar collar) {
        this.name = name;
        this.collar = collar;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Collar getCollar() {
        return collar;
    }

    public void setCollar(Collar collar) {
        this.collar = collar;
    }

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream os) {
        try {
            os.defaultWriteObject();
            os.writeUTF(collar.getName());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream is) {
        try {
            is.defaultReadObject();
            collar = new Collar(is.readUTF(), null);  // here, need a collar.getCobbar()
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "dog name : " + this.name + "   collar : " + this.collar;
    }
}
```

### **Collar.java**

```
package main;

public class Collar {
    private String name;
    private Cobbar cobbar;

    public Collar(String name, Cobbar cobbar) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cobbar = cobbar;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "collar name : " + this.name + " cobbar : " + cobbar;
    }

}
```

### **Cobbar.java**

```
package main;

public class Cobbar {
    private String name;

    public Cobbar(String name) {
        this.name  = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "cobbar name : " + name;
    }

}
```

### **MyClass.java**

```
package main;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cobbar cobbar = new Cobbar("Cobbar object");
        Collar collar = new Collar("Collar object", cobbar);
        Dog dog = new Dog("Dog object", collar);


        try {
            FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream("D:\\SCJPsimple.txt");
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fis);
            os.writeObject(dog);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:\\SCJPsimple.txt");
            ObjectInputStream os = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            dog = (Dog) os.readObject();

            System.out.println("Dog str : " + dog.toString());

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `transient` keyword means "don't serialize", so the simple answer to make your `Dog` class `Serializable` is to simply "remove the `transient` keyword".

The full answer is to make will nested classes `Serializable` too:

```
public class Dog implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private Collar collar;

    // rest of class omitted
}

public class Collar implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private Cobbar cobbar;
    // rest of class omitted
}

public class Cobbar implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    // rest of class omitted
}
```

Most classes from the JDK are `Serializable`, so your `String` fields etc will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add custom writeObject() and readObject() methods to Dog, or to Collar, or make the field non-transient, or add a 'serializableFields' member.